# Alterar tamanho da fonte nativa

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo e gostaria de saber se é possível aumentar a fonte padrão do Android? De média para grande. E se for, é complexo? Tentei com TextAppearence.Large como style mas não consegui.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema Darlan, ou precisa de mais alguma informação?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode definir o tamanho da fonte além da propriedade `android:textAppearance`, usando esta, `android:textSize`

Exemplo:

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="50sp"/>
```

Comment: Até fiz isso, mas preciso definir tamanho da fonte da aplicação. Como se fosse ir em "Configurações" do dispositivo e alterar para Grande. Mas via código.

Comment: Então você não quer definir o tamanho da fonte da sua aplicação, mas sim que seu app alterasse o tamanho da fonte de todo o sistema? Seria isto?

Comment: Exatamente. Do meu aplicativo não precisa, pois já está todo definido. Acha que é difícil implementar?

Answer (score 0):

Seria melhor você colocar o seu código aqui para vermos possíveis erros no seu código.

Mas faça o seguinte teste, no seu estilo principal coloque o item TextSize

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">@style/TextSize</item>
</style>
```

Crie o style TextSize definido acima

```
<style name="TextSize">
   <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

Agora lá no seu **AndroidManifest.xml** na tag **application** você confere se tem o tema definido:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```

Comment: Mas a minha intenção seria alterar a fonte do android (nativa). Mas de qualquer forma, irei testar e dar um feedback. Caso não tenha solução, teria como utilizar API para chamar essa função?

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode alterar um tamanho de **fonte padrão**, porém você pode definir um tema e onde é possível alterar o tamanho de fonte. Para saber mais, você pode ler sobre [Estilos e temas](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) na documentação de referência do desenvolvedor Android.

Exemplo de definição do tema:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

Desta forma acima, você definirá um tamanho padrão para todos os `TextView` dentro de sua aplicação. Para definir um tamanho específico individualmente, você pode fazer desta forma:

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Trump eh o novo presidente dos EUA"
   android:textSize="40sp"/>
```

Tente usar sempre `SP`, pois é dimensionada independentemente em relação ao tamanho de fonte normal do dispositivo.

Detalhes

- [Compatibilidade com várias telas](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Até fiz isso, mas preciso definir tamanho da fonte da aplicação. Como se fosse ir em "Configurações" do dispositivo e alterar para Grande. Mas via código.